# how to configuration vim-easytags for javascript

Tags: vim

I want to use [vim-easytags](https://github.com/xolox/vim-easytags) for javascript, so that it can use jsctags to generate tags each time I save my code. From the documentation of vim-easytags, I notice it supports javascript tags and `jsctags`. But how to set the configuration struggled me. Can anyone help me fix my `.vimrc`?

```
let g:easytags_python_enabled=1
let g:easytags_events = ['BufWritePost']
let b:easytags_auto_highlight = 1
let g:easytags_async=1
let g:easytags_by_filetype=1
let g:easytags_languages = {
\   'javascript': {
\       'cmd': 'jsctags',
\       'args': ['-f'],
\       'fileoutput_opt': '-f',
\       'stdout_opt': '-f-',
\       'recurse_flag': '-R'
\   }
\}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do it for me:

```
let g:easytags_languages = {
\   'javascript': {
\       'cmd': 'jsctags',
\       'recurse_flag': ''
\   }
\}
```